# Template partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates

Would any one knows according to what rules code below doesn't compile?

```
template <class T>
struct B
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<class T>
struct X
{
};
template<class T>
struct X<B<T>::type*>//HERE I'M PARTIALLY SPECIALIZING (WELL, TRYING TO...)
{
};
```

Please see comment inside the code.

Answer (score 11):

How do you think that will work? The compiler will look to see if there is a class T somewhere that has a typedef "type" to your class?

It just won't. Even though it's a pointer.

Remember that presumably your B template is presumably specialised in places so that type is not always T*, but it can't deduce it with reverse engineering.

For those who did not understand my answer fully, what you are asking the compiler to do is find a class U such that B::type is the class you pass in as a parameter.

```
class Foo;
class Bar;

template<> struct B<Foo>
{
  typedef int type;
};

template<> struct B<Bar>
{
  typedef int type;
};

X<int*> // ambiguous, T is Foo or Bar?
```

It is difficult to know exactly why you are trying to do what you are. You can do a partial specialization on all pointers and then a total specialization on specific pointers, which could be implement in terms of another template.

Comment: I don’t really understand this answer. The compiler *knows* which class to use – `B<T>`. Whenever `X` is instantiated, the compiler is absolutely capable of searching through all partial specializations of `X` for the most specific. In fact, that’s what it *always* does. Consequently, Nawaz’ answer is correct.

Comment: (Continued) Or rather, I’d *expect* Nawaz’ answer to be correct. Clearly it doesn’t work but I fail to understand the compiler’s complaint (GCC’s message is similar to VS 2010’s).

Comment: @Kondrad Nawaz's answer cannot be correct if it doesn't compile, that's what I would think anyway.

Comment: @Kondrad to your last comment: That exactly what I'm stuck with. According to which "bullet" in std this doesn't compile?

Comment: @Konrad and @There is nothing :  I'm also wondering what my code isn't compiling, although it seems correct to me. http://ideone.com/iwnuE

Comment: The compiler does not know what class to use. It is looking for a class U such that B<U>::type is T. It may happen that U=T but there is no such guarantee.

Comment: @CashCow “It is looking for a class U such that B<U>::type is T” – Why should it? `T` is bound and well-known in the context so it should look for `B<T>::type`, not for `B<U>::type` for some `U`. The compiler should be able to perform a straightforward substitution here.

Comment: @Konrad look at the definition of the template, it is not X<T> it is X<typename B<T>::type> the T in the template definition above is deceptive. In my example you would write X<int*> not X<Foo*> or X<Bar*>

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `typename` keyword as,

```
template<class T>
struct X<typename B<T>::type*>
{
};
```

It's because `B<T>::type` is a dependent name. So `typename` is required!

--

EDIT:

Even after putting `typename`, it isn't compiling. I think it's because deduction of type `T` in `B<T>` from `X<U>` is difficult, or possibly impossible, for the compiler. So I believe its non-deduced context.

See a similar example here and the discussion:

[Template parameters in non-deduced contexts in partial specializations](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2008-01/msg00482.html)

---

However, if you change the specialization to this:

```
template<class T>
struct X<B<T> >
{
};
```

Then it becomes the deducible context, and so would compile.

Comment: @Navaz I did as you proposed and I've got: Error 1 error C2764: 'T' : template parameter not used or deducible in partial specialization 'X<B<T>::type*>' from VS 2010

Comment: @There is nothing. Because it can't. What you are trying to do is beyond the scope of the compiler.

Comment: @CashCow what do you mean by beyond the scope of compiler (and please, I'm not trying to have a go with you or with anyone here, I'm just trying to understand)

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: Please see my edit. And the link to a good topic discussing the same problem!

Comment: @Nawaz indeed your second one would be deducible, B<T> can only ever mean one thing here.

Comment: It should compile, I think. It just should never match that specialization.

Comment: @Johannes: The specialization doesn't compile. See this yourself : http://ideone.com/iwnuE

Comment: I said "It should compile". I didn't say "Ideone accepts this". It probably is a warning that was output as an error because of -Werror and if not then it's possibly a GCC bug. I'm talking from memory, so I might be wrong. See core issue 549 for the issue report for this http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#549 . You could apply rule 14.6p8 ("If no valid specialization can be generated..."), but that's a very weak rule to use for emitting a diagnostic here, in my opinion and I think it hasn't got non-deduced contexts of partial specializations in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already added `typename` as suggested by Nawaz.

The problem is exactly explained in the error message you encounter: "template parameter is not deducible in partial specialization `B<T>::type*`. The problem is that `B<T>::type` and `T` is exactly the same for all types `T`. Consider the following example:

```
class MyClass1 {};
typedef typename B<MyClass>::type MyClass2; //(*)

X<MyClass*> obj1;
X<MyClass2*> obj2;
```

The result of line `(*)` is a type MyClass2 which is essentially `MyClass1`. So, `obj1` and `obj2` should be objects of the same class. Now, which version of template `X` should they use?

If you would expect the specialised version of `X`, tell me if the answer should be the same if line `(*)` is removed (and obviously `obj2` as well). Still `obj1` should be the specialised version of `X` as line `(*)` has nothing to do with it.

But now we expect the compiler to detect that some type can be potentially declared as `B<T>::type` although we never do this. We expect the compiler to verify all possible template instantiations to check if there is no strange typedef in one of them.

I hope this clarifies why such specialisation cannot be handled by the compiler.

---

**An alternative that might help**

I believe your problem could be attacked by creating a trait class for explicitly marking types that should be handled in a special way. Something like this:

```
template <bool v>
struct boolean_value {
  static const bool value=v;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_my_interesting_type : public boolean_value<false> {};

class MyClass {
  ...
};

template <>
struct is_my_interesting_type<MyClass> : public boolean_value<true> {};

template <typename T, bool special>
class  InternalX {
  ... //generic version of your template X
};

template <typename T>
class InternalX<T,true> {
  ... //special version of your template X
};

template <typename T>
class X : public InternalX<T,is_my_interesting_type<T>::value> {};
```

Also, you might be interesting how it is done in boost library, in particular [Boost.Type_Traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: “The problem is that `B<T>::type` and `T` is exactly the same for all types `T`” – No. That is *not* a problem (or should not be). “Now, which version of template X should they use?” – Obviously the specialized version because your types are both pointers. The usage of `B<T>::type` instead of just `T` here is completely irrelevant. What’s relevant is that the specialization is a *pointer*.

Comment: If you want to have specialised version for all pointeres you should have `X<T*>` and not `X<B<T>::type*>`. The latter suggests that you want the specialisation only for _some_ pointers but not all of them. _That_, and not the fact that you have a pointer, is a problem. You will get exactly the same error if you remove `*`.

Comment: "The usage of B<T>::type instead of just T here is completely irrelevant" -> it is relevant and crucial for the compiler. It cannot deduct what `B<T>` is needed to get a match with current type that you want instantiate with. Morover, he doesn't even know that he should actually look into template class B when searching for a match.

Comment: Why is it a problem though? Why can it not deduce `B<T>`? (In fact, there is no deduction, it’s a straightforward replacing).

Comment: Imagine you have 1000 template classes which have typedefs inside. Do you think the compiler will check all of them for a match? And what if there are more than one match?

Answer (score 0):

"The argument list cannot be identical to the non-specialized argument list (it must specialize something)"
see [partial_specialization at en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization)