# defining hash function for nested custom type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, hash, compiler-errors

Given a nested template class structure like the following:

```
template<class T> class A
{
  ...
public:
  ...
  class B;
};
```

I am wanting the std::hash function to work on the nested class so that it can be put in things like unsorted_map and unsorted_set, so I defined the nested class as:

```
template<class T> class A<T>::B 
{
  public:
    bool operator==(const A<T>::B &) const;
  ...
  friend struct std::hash<A<T>::B>;
};
```

And then tried adding a specialized std::hash structure for this type as follows:

```
namespace std
{
  template<class T> struct hash<A<T>::B>
  {
    bool operator()(const A<T>::B &x) const
    {
       ...
    }
  };
}
```

But the compiler complains vehemently when I try to define the custom std::hash function object like this.

The error message I get is unhelpful, as follows:

```
xyz.cc:17:38: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp> struct std::hash'
 template<class T> struct hash<A<T>::B>
                                      ^
xyz.cc:17:38: error:   expected a type, got 'A<T>::B'
```

I'm not sure how else I am supposed to express it, however.

Why is this wrong, and what must I do to to fix it?

Comment: Can you add the complaint from your compiler?

Comment: Well, that particular error says you need `typename`.

Comment: I tried  `struct hash<A<typename T>::B>`, and `struct hash<typename A<typename T>::B>`, which both give the error `template argument 1 is invalid`, and `struct hash<typename A<T>::B>` gives the error `template parameters not used in partial specialization`.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5211205/315052

Comment: From what I gather, the only out is define `B` outside of `A`. Either that, or define a specialization for `hash` for each `T` you plan to pass to `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

Dependant types cannot be pattern matched against, as the general case requires inverting an arbitrary Turing-complete algorithm.

The easiest way is to make `B` an independant template, then typedef into `A`.