# Compile error defining a std::hash for a template class nested class

Tags: c++, templates, hash, nested

I have a class:

```
namespace App
{

template<typename A, typename B>
class MyClass
{
    //...
    class NestedClass
    {
        //...
    }
}

} //namespace App
```

I would like to define a std::hash for NestedClass

```
//Definition of hash functions
namespace std
{
    //Definition of a hash to use generic pairs as key
    template<typename A, typename B>
    struct hash<App::MyClass<A,B>::NestedClass>
    {
    public:
        size_t operator()(const App::MyClass<A,B>::NestedClass &it) const
        {
            return std::hash(it.toInt());
        }
    };
}
```

I get the error:

```
source.h:1166: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp> struct std::hash'
  struct hash<App::MyClass<A,B>::const_NestedClass>
                                                  ^
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: nestedclass is private?  also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: When naming a type defined by a templated type, you have to specify that it is a type with `typename`. Try `typename App::MyClass<A,B>::NestedClass` instead.

Comment: @xaxxon If you write MCVE in square brackets you get this: [MCVE]

Comment: @Jonas very helpful, thank you.  \[mcve\]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix your error by adding `typename` where appropriate to inform the compiler that the symbol following `::` is indeed a type:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct hash<typename App::MyClass<A, B>::NestedClass>
{//         ^^^^^^^^
public:
    size_t operator()(const typename App::MyClass<A,B>::NestedClass &it) const
//                          ^^^^^^^^
    {
        return hash(it.toInt());
    }
};
```

Now you get a new error:

```
prog.cc:22:12: error: class template partial specialization contains template parameters that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used [-Wunusable-partial-specialization]
    struct hash<typename App::MyClass<A, B>::NestedClass>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:21:23: note: non-deducible template parameter 'A'
    template<typename A, typename B>
                      ^
prog.cc:21:35: note: non-deducible template parameter 'B'
    template<typename A, typename B>
```

It is impossible for the compiler to deduce `A` and `B` in this context, as there's no guarantee that `NestedClass` exists for all `MyClass<A, B>` instantiations. More information:

- [SO: "Template partial specialization"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211205/template-partial-specialization)
- [SO: "Template parameters not used in partial specialization"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398912/template-parameters-not-used-in-partial-specialization)

You'll probably be able to work around this by assuming that `NestedClass` exists and hashing on `MyClass<A, B>` instead. Provide some way of accessing `NestedClass`from `MyClass` and you'll be able to write something like this:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct hash<typename App::MyClass<A, B>>
{
public:
    size_t operator()(const typename App::MyClass<A,B> &it) const
    {       
        return hash(it.nested.toInt());
    }
};
```

Comment: This is not applicable, as nested is not a simple member of the main class. It is a kind of persistent iterator used for navigating inside the main object

Comment: OK, this means I cannot use NestedClass for a standard hash container directly, unless I fully specialize the main class.

Comment: @galinette: can you move `NestedClass` outside of its parent class and templatize it over `<A, B>`?

Comment: @galinette Could you pass in the hasher as a template parameter to whatever container you're using?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo : this would do the job, it would be less pretty as the nested class is basically an iterator, but I'll do it as a workaround

Comment: @galinette: sounds like a job for a `detail::` namespace :P