# Specialize trait using type defined in template struct

Tags: c++, struct, type-traits, unreal-engine5

How can I specialise a trait using a type when it's definition is nested in a template type ?

Here is an example of what I'm doing and what I want:

```cpp
// A trait that can be specialized
template<typename T>
struct MyTrait
{
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};
//This base case works fine
struct ClassicStruct 
{
    struct ClassicNestedType {};
};
//Inside this template struct I defined a Type
template<typename T> 
struct TemplateStruct
{
    struct DefinedInTemplate
    {
        T val;
    };

};
//=======THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DO, and it doesn't compile ==========
template<typename T>
struct MyTrait<TemplateStruct<T>::DefinedInTemplate>
{
    static constexpr int value = 589;

};
//This works fine
template<>
struct MyTrait<bool>
{
    static constexpr int value = 4;
};
//perfectly fine too
template<typename T>
struct MyTrait<TemplateStruct<T>>
{
    static constexpr int value = 254;

};
//Another example that is perfectly fine
template<>
struct MyTrait<ClassicStruct::ClassicNestedType>
{
    static constexpr int value = 468;

};

int main()
{
    printf("value of main: %d \n", MyTrait<TemplateStruct<int>>::value);//prints 254
    printf("value of main: %d \n", MyTrait<TemplateStruct<int>::DefinedInTemplate>::value); //I wish it would print 589 here
    printf("value of main: %d \n", MyTrait<ClassicStruct::ClassicNestedType>::value);//prints 468
}
```

in GCC the compile error is

> type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for
> 'template struct MyTrait'    27 | struct
> MyTrait<TemplateStruct::DefinedInTemplate>

That error is weird, `TemplateStruct<T>::DefinedInTemplate` is a type no ?

It should be noted that in my real case I can't replace the trait by a concept or something else. This is in UE5 where I must specialise an existing trait. So I can't get around specialising a trait, and I can't really modify that trait, as I'm trying to avoid editing the engine code. This trait is used a lot and I wouldn't be very comfortable touching it.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Template partial specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211205/template-partial-specialization) because of **non deduced context**

Comment: Note that you need to add `typename` but still the program won't compile because of [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-non-deduced-context). See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oT5r9e44W) Also see [When is the "typename" keyword necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `T` in `TemplateStruct<T>::DefinedInTemplate` is in a non-deduced context. Given just any type, we can't tell if it is `TemplateStruct<T>::DefinedInTemplate` for some `T` directly with existing C++ tools. It may be possible with C++ reflections in future versions.

A C++20 solution is to make a concept and partially specialise based on that:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept IsDefinedInTemplateInsideTemplateStruct =
    std::same_as<T, typename TemplateStruct<decltype(T::val)>::DefinedInTemplate>;

template<IsDefinedInTemplateInsideTemplateStruct T>
struct MyTrait<T>
{
    static constexpr int value = 589;
};
```

A C++11 solution would be to make `DefinedInTemplate` an alias for some external template:

```cpp
namespace impl {
    template<typename T>
    struct TemplateStructInnerClass {
        T val;
    };
}

template<typename T>
struct TemplateStruct {
    using DefinedInTemplate = impl::TemplateStructInnerClass<T>;
};

template<typename T>
struct MyTrait<impl::TemplateStructInnerClass<T>>
{
    static constexpr int value = 589;
};
```

Comment: OP explicitly said *"I can't replace the trait by a concept or something else..."*. Also this already has many [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211205/template-partial-specialization).

Comment: @user12002570 They said they can't replace the trait but this still uses the trait. None of the duplicates provide a solution to the exact problem given, and I have had to use the solutions given here before for `std::hash` specializations.

Comment: This is actually a very good answer, I can't replace the trait but with this solution I don't need to. The concept will only need to exist in "my" code without touching the engine stuffs. And I don't believe the duplicate questions answer the question I had, and this one does.

Comment: afaik its not just because "we can't tell ... with existing C++ tools" but rather because there is no 1:1 relation between that type and `T`. There can be many different instantiations `TemplateStruct<U>` whose `DefinedInTemplate` is the same, hence given some `DefinedInTemplate` there is no way to tell which `T` to choose